# IndexedDB retrieve subset of properties

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I store objects that look like this:

```
{
  name : 'name',
  dateJoined: 1391493086747,
  balance: 10,
  currency: '$'
}
```

I want to make a request for a subset of these properties, for example just 'name' and 'dateJoined'. Is this possible in IndexedDB? I know I can get the results and make shallow copies myself, but I want to spare the garbage collector. Basically I want the equivalent of this SQL statement:

```
 SELECT name, dateJoined FROM users
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible. If you have some small data that you commonly use and huge data that you rarely use, it might make sense to split them across two object stores, but you should do some benchmarks first to see if it actually matters. For most purposes, the performance will probably be good enough as is.